# I cannot invoke wcf methods using Browser(HTTP)

Tags: wcf, http, browser

I have a service with below code

#### TaskService.svc

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TodoService : ITodoService
{
    private readonly List<Todo> _dataSource;

    public TodoService()
    {
        _dataSource = new List<Todo>();
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Todos")]
    public List<Todo> Todos()
    {
        return _dataSource;
    }
}
```

and the data transfer object is as below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITodoService
{
    [OperationContract]        
    List<Todo> Todos();
}

[DataContract]
public class Todo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

}
```

the web.config as below

```
<services>
  <service name="SampleService.TodosBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SampleService.TodosBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SampleService.TodoService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SampleService.TodosBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

the application is hosted in IIS 7 with virtual directory `SampleService`. When ever i invoke using browser `http://localhost/SampleService/TaskService.svc/Todos` i am greeted with nothing. But i expected a empty array. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the WebGet() needs to be in your interface (ServiceContract) rather than your implementation of that interface. Also, do you need the slash before "Todos" in your UriTemplate?

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TodoService : ITodoService
{
    private readonly List<Todo> _dataSource;

    public TodoService()
    {
        _dataSource = new List<Todo>();
    }

    public List<Todo> Todos()
    {
        return _dataSource;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITodoService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Todos")]
    [OperationContract]        
    List<Todo> Todos();
}
```

If you're hosting in IIS, what does your TaskService.svc file look like?

EDIT: Oh, this IS your .svc file. Never mind then.

Comment: now i hit with error `Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.`

Comment: Yeah, you can't use WebScriptEnablingBehavior with UriTemplates. For REST services, you want to use System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory